# What is Microsoft Azure Memory Percent MySQL metric

Tags: mysql, azure

Documentation says it is The percentage of memory in use, but what kind of memory is it? 
Looking at the Metrics for past week, this only goes up, and never down.

**Graph from azure metrics**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its address space usage on your MYSQL instance. It's not overly surprising that it's going up like that, as you add more data or run queries that are cached etc. it will increase the memory usage.

Comment: So, this is RAM used? And system never clears it?

Comment: It's not up to the system to clean it up. You're running a database, databases use memory, and the more data you put in it or queries your run the more memory it will use. Many databases will use as much memory as they can get to make queries faster. If the system is restarted or you drop a load of data it will do down for a while.